# Intellij IDEA 13.1 isn't creating new Grails Projects

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, ide

My Intellij IDEA 13.1.4 Ultimate isn't creating new Grails projects using "File" > "New Project".

I mark my project as Groovy Project then I select Grails. I setup a Groovy Library pointing to my Grails 2.4.3 home (I've tried with 2.3.11 and 2.2.5). I click Next and put a name for my project.

Then, when I finish this process, the Intellij Window opens but the Grails "create-app" script doesn't runs and the project isn't properly configured. The folders like "grails-app" and "web-app" aren't created. No log error or warn was generated.

Importing an project works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a bug in IDEA, see [IDEA-127693](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127693)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of choosing grails in the menu choose groovy and then select the grails library like this:

[image: selecting groovy]

that will somehow trigger the create-app script

Comment: this trick doesn't work with intellij 14.1.5 and Grails 3.0.8